# What does "ramified" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a line from the movie [The Ballad of Buster Scruggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Buster_Scruggs):

> (Buster Scruggs to the camera, supposedly to the viewer, before turning to face an opponent in a gunfight duel): Things have a way of escalating out here in the West with one thing leading to another, but I should be able to make pretty short work of this **ramified** old son-of-a-gun.

Dictionaries define **ramify** as *to spread out*, but I don't see how that can fit in this context. What does it mean here?

Comment: Have not seen the movie, but perhaps it means the old son-of-a-gun no longer has his wits about him, and so Buster Scruggs believes he can make short work of him.

Comment: Haven't seen the movie, but in westerns and spoofs of westerns there is the possibility that it is a malapropism.  A plant "ramifies" into shoots or branches from a main stalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Merriam-Webster](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ramify):

> Ramify has been part of English since the 15th century and is an offshoot of the Latin word for "branch," which is "ramus." English acquired several scientific words from "ramus," including "biramous" ("having two branches"). Another English word derived from "ramus" is **the now obsolete ramage, meaning "untamed" or "wild."** "Ramage" originated in falconry-it was initially used of young hawks that had begun to fly from branch to branch in trees.

I expect the person who wrote this particular vignette read the term "ramified" in some Old West novel or newspaper article and decided it would sound good in the script, even if the intended meaning is not quite correct.  It's certainly rare enough that few would know what it meant out of context, but in the film we can (more or less) guess what Buster is saying about his opponent.

Comment: And what is he saying?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Any word paired with "son of a gun" is likely to be some kind of aspersion.  The exact meaning is unimportant.

Comment: Based on the definition, a ***ramified*** *old son-of-a-gun* is a ***wild*** *old son-of-a-gun*. To analyze it further, *wild* could stand for *erratic* or *unskilled*. In other words, Buster Scruggs considers himself more skilled and in no danger of losing the duel.

Comment: @JasonBassford  or just *angry*.

Answer (score 1):

Wright in his *English Dialect Dictionary* cites attestations for **ramified** where the word is used to refer to crops which are choked with a "rubbishy" growth. So the word could be a synonym for "worthless" or "no good"—an aspersion, as Andrew says in a comment above.